# Finding positive solution of Diophantine Equation with two variables

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have an equation **ax + by = N**. Now **a**, **b** and **N** are positive so I need to find positive solution **(x & y)** if exists.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Do you have any ideas on how to approach the problem?

Comment: I am not able to figure out when no positive solution exits even **gcd(a, b)** divides **N**.

Comment: I found the answer over here .. https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/21-127/lectures/divisibility_5_print.pdf

Comment: @DebasisJana Do you know how to determine the general integer solution ?

Comment: extended eucludean algorithm to find x and y for **ax + by = gcd(a,b)**. Now to find a solution for equation **aX+bY = N** and **N/gcd(a,b) = k** then we get **akx + bky = gcd(a,b)k** then we can get a solution for X and Y